# PC to projector HDMI handshake issue

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, projector, hdcp

I think I have a HDMI/HDCP handshake issue with my projector. I have had an [Optoma EW628 projector](http://www.projectorsmanual.com/manuals/optoma/Optoma_EW628.pdf) hooked up to my desktop PC for about 2 years which has always worked perfectly.

I'm running Windows 10, and the graphics card is an admittedly old [Intel HD Graphics 2000](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-2nd-generation-intel-processors/intel-hd-graphics-2000.html). I have an HDMI lead plugged into the HDMI port on the PC with the other end plugged into the projector via an HDMI to DVI convertor, as it does not have an HDMI port.

As I say, this set up has worked fine for around 2 years until this week, when I had [Sky Q](http://www.sky.com/shop/tv/sky-q/) installed. For those that aren't familiar, Sky Q is a digital TV home network that has a [master box](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/skygroup-sky-static/documents/sky-q-2015/fact_sheet_skyq_2tb_box.pdf) connected to a satellite dish, which then uses home Wifi network to stream content to connected [mini boxes](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/skygroup-sky-static/documents/sky-q-2015/fact-sheet-sky-q-mini.pdf) in other rooms around the home.

I used a [HDMI splitter](https://freeshipdeals.com/products/3-way-hdmi-splitter?variant=45541490122&gclid=CjwKCAjww9_MBRAWEiwAlaMJZkXuYdvWmTI_KgQNA29YeUVhscAJRMTzjhv1at8q_QyzpTJ23dnUYxoCYYwQAvD_BwE) to connect the sky box to the projector as well as the PC, and this seemed to work fine for a short time. I could switch between the two signals without issue by pressing the switch on the splitter.

However, all of a sudden the PC is unable to detect the projector.

Things I have checked:

I have removed the splitter completely and

1. Connected the projector directly to PC: **no signal on projector**
2. Connected the projector directly to Sky box: **signal comes through fine**
3. Connected another HD monitor to PC via same HDMI cable: **signal comes through fine**
4. Connected another laptop (with [Intel HD Graphics 5300 card](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-5300.125576.0.html)) via HDMI cable directly to projector: **no signal on projector**
5. Connected another laptop (with [Intel HD Graphics 5300 card](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-5300.125576.0.html)) via same HDMI cable directly to another HD monitor: **signal comes through fine**
6. Connected another PS3 via HDMI cable directly to projector: **no signal on projector**
7. Connected another PS3 via HDMI cable directly to HD TV: **signal comes through fine**

So it seems that the projector will now only recognise the signal from the Sky Q mini box and nothing else.

I have tried the usual process of connecting a projector to Windows as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/27911/windows-10-connect-to-a-projector-or-pc) to no avail.

I have also come across a few posts describing similar issues [here](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/68-digital-projectors-under-3-000-usd-msrp/1511566-handshake-issue-optoma-hd131xe.html), [here](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/1459056-how-do-i-reset-hdcp-handshake-between-pc-receiver.html) and [here](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/26-home-theater-computers/2598665-here-s-potential-solution-hdmi-handshake-driver-problems.html) and what I have surmised from those is that connecting the Sky Q mini box has caused some kind of HDMI/HDCP handshake issue that has encrypted the connection and only the sky Q connection can bypass it.

Does that sound feasible? If so, is there a way round it? It seems that the issue is with the projector, so is there a way to do a firmware upgrade? Or get in to the engineer menu and do a factory reset or something?

Or could it be that something is fried in the projector now? and if that means I need to go out and buy a new one, what are the chances of this happening again?

This is completely frustrating as it ran without issue for so long and is still happy to display the Sky Q signal.

**--UPDATE--**

I have managed to access the service menu by pressing *Power, <, <, Menu* on the remote control. I saw that there was a "Factory Reset" option which I was hoping would return the firmware to it's original state and begin picking up the signal from the PC.

Unfortunately this has not happened, it still ignores the PC and laptop when both are connected directly via HDMI. VGA connection works fine.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?

Comment: What happens if you connect both the projector and a monitor to your PC (assuming your PC has more than one display output; if not, try the laptop you used in 4. and 5.)? Does Windows recognize and list the projector properly? If yes, can you manually switch to it?

Comment: @uSlackr, I am using Windows 10 Pro version 1703

Comment: @Nassbirne there is only one hdmi output on the PC, a display port and a DVI. I have dual monitors and the projector. The PC used to list the projector when both monitors were connected (one to display port, one to DVI, with projector connected to the HDMI), now it doesn't

Comment: I would say try connecting to this think via RS232 connection and going thru the options (page 53 in the link manual) there to try to factory reset this thing before buying another. I would also may try some of the button factory reset that may be applicable if you're at the trash it and replace stage—Not sure how accurate these methods are for example: https://i.imgur.com/gJNsjtI.png. I would consider reaching out to the vendor of this product as well to see what support they will give you. If they cannot help, then consider another product of the same functionality with better support.

Comment: I also poked around this vendor website and I am not impressed. I would shop around for similar products from other vendors that will suffice for your need too and not just be stuck with Optoma products for this sort of hardware. Support and getting answers to questions when you have problem should help you determine if this is a vendor you want to stick with for example. Does it not come with a warranty for example—live and learn and things to consider, question, and think about should you need to last resort replace if a wipe will not fix or some other solution.

Comment: I have managed to access the service menu by pressing *Power, <, <, Menu* on the remote control. I saw that there was a "Factory Reset" option which I was hoping would return the firmware to it's original state and begin picking up the signal from the PC. 

Unfortunately this has not happened, it still ignores the PC and laptop when both are connected directly via HDMI. VGA connection works fine.

Comment: After reset of the firmware, could you try to disconnect the projector completely (all cables) for some time (30 minutes?) for complete power down? In one forum post related to an Optoma problem I found that helped with handshake issue.

Comment: Please note that doing a factory reset is not a firmware downgrade or upgrade. I'd still connect via RS 232 cable, and go thru the reset motions there. I saw that there are reset options within multiple areas so be sure you do a factory / default reset to the entire device and not just settings per one particular screen. Perhaps that's the option you saw via the remote controller; I'd still connect via RS232 and wipe the thing from there or downgrade or update the firmware. Note again, firmware upgrade/downgrade is not the same as factory reset. I'd call support and make it their problem—POS.